# How to use Tomcat with Eclipse Luna GWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

My problem is for use default project of gwt in Eclipse Luna with Tomcat server version 7, but  my project is never deployed.

I have add project in Tomcat:

[image]

When I use run as with Google super dev mod no problem. I have index page of tomcat in localhost:8080 so tomcat run. But my project is not deployed :

```
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule     begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Project' did not find a matching property.
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:          Feb 8 2016 20:25:54 UTC
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:         7.0.68.0
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:            6.3
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:           1.7.0_80-b15
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\user\workspaceluna\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\serveur\apache-7
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\user\workspaceluna\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\serveur\apache-7
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\user\workspaceluna\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\serveur\apache-7\endorsed
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\NVIDIA CORPORATION\PHYSX\COMMON;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\ACER\ABFILES\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\GNUstep\bin;C:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools;C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin;.
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 853 ms
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
mars 27, 2016 10:37:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mars 27, 2016 10:37:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
mars 27, 2016 10:37:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mars 27, 2016 10:37:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mars 27, 2016 10:37:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 1039 ms
```

thanks for you help.